JOOQ Multiset is coming back as json array instead of Record
I have simpler examples where using a multiset works fine, however I am now nesting it in a CTE and JOOQ seems to be converting it to an array rather than keeping it as a record.
This is about as simple as an example as I can get:
    val table = DSL.select(
        PROXY_VOTE.asterisk(),
        multiset(
            DSL.selectFrom(TAG)
                .where(TAG.PROXY_VOTE_ID.eq(PROXY_VOTE.ID))
        )
            .`as`("tags"),
    )
        .from(PROXY_VOTE)


    val cte = with("cte").`as`(table)
        .select(
            asterisk(),
            DSL.count().over().`as`("total_count")
        ).from(name("cte"))

    val results = this
        .with("cte2").`as`(cte)
        .select()
        .from("cte2")
        .fetch()

If you then do this:
results.first().getValue("tags", List::class.java)
You'll see that you get back json arrays instead of TagRecords. I don't mind converting them back to TagRecords myself, however I'm not sure how you do that in an automatic way (all I seem to find is manually mapping each field, which is a no go).
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

You're not giving jOOQ any information about the types involved with your query when you do this:
select(
    asterisk(),
    DSL.count().over().`as`("total_count")
).from(name("cte"))

The problem is that your cte is referenced using name("cte"), and while jOOQ could in principle try to look up this table from the WITH clause, it doesn't. Why not provide it explicitly, though?
val cte = DSL.name("cte").as(DSL.select(
    PROXY_VOTE.asterisk(),
    multiset(
        DSL.selectFrom(TAG)
            .where(TAG.PROXY_VOTE_ID.eq(PROXY_VOTE.ID))
    )
        .`as`("tags"),
)
    .from(PROXY_VOTE))

val cte = with(cte)
    .select(
        asterisk(),
        DSL.count().over().`as`("total_count")
    ).from(cte)

Of course, you could still take this a step further by omitting reflection in your mapper as well, and trying to model this as a type safe query instead. That way, you'll have even more certainty about whether this query will run correctly at runtime. But that's not the main issue of your question, so the above should probably already do the trick.
